# For loop for HTML table

Tags: javascript, html-table

Could someone please tell me what I have done wrong here? I am trying to use input coordinates to output to a html table using for loops.

```
for(i=1; i<10; i++);{
    i = x;
    document.writeln(mytable + i)
}    
    for(j=1; j<10; j++);{
    j = y;
    document.writeln(mytable + j)
    }
        if(kingX == x || kingY == y){
        document.writeln('K');
        }
            else if(queenX == x || queenY == y){
            document.writeln('Q');
            }
                else(x || y <=10);{
                document.writeln(' ');
                }

mytable = mytable + "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

Comment: What indication do you have that there's a problem?  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?

Comment: You've described what you expect this code *should* do, but haven't described what it *does* do.  How does this fail?  As for debugging, look at the debugging tools in your browser.  You can set "breakpoints" in your code and step through it, line by line, as it executes.  This allows you to examine the runtime values of variables, see how the logic behaves, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've rewritten your code so you can see what it is supposed to look like.

```
<script>
var isInCheck = '';

var kingX  = prompt('Enter X co-ordinate of King? ','');
var kingY  = prompt('Enter Y co-ordinate of King? ','');
var queenX = prompt('Enter X co-ordinate of Queen? ','');
var queenY = prompt('Enter Y co-ordinate of Queen? ','');

document.write('<table>');

for ( var x=0; x<10; x++) {
    document.writeln('<tr>');
    for (var y=0; y<10; y++) {
        // This is inside of a nested for-loop
        document.writeln('<td>');
        if (kingX == x && kingY == y) {
            document.writeln('K');
        } else if(queenX == x && queenY == y) {
            document.writeln('Q');
        } else {
            document.writeln(' ');
        }
        document.writeln('</td>');
    }
    document.writeln('</tr>');
}

document.write( '</table>' );
</script>
```

There are 2 major mistakes in the code you posted.

The first one, do not do this because the semi-colon will not execute the code between the curly braces:

```
for(j=1; j<10; j++);{
```

It should look like this (no semi-colon):

```
for(j=1; j<10; j++) {
```

That is probably the main source of the confusion you may have had.

Second, you want to do this:

```
if (kingX == x && kingY == y) {
```

Not this:

```
if (kingX == x || kingY == y) {
```

The code you wrote is saying: if the x coordinate is equal kingX, OR the y coordinate is equal kingY then display a K.  You want both conditions to be true so you need and want to use &&.

Additionally, for-loops can also be nested, you can have a loop within another loop which is necessary to create the table structure you want.

And, lastly, it is not common to use document.write to output a table but since you are a beginner it is okay.  Usually we'll concatenate a string with a variable then just output that variable.